# What is the best way to install Debian to a PC without a CD or DVD drive?

Tags: linux, debian-installer, data-cd

I built a PC a few years ago, and didn't include an opticall drive (CD or DVD). I don't know who uses them anymore but I don't.

Now I want to install Debian to the PC, but it wants to detect a CD-ROM. Did I miss any point or is it still a thing?

Comment: Does it want to, or is it just asking? What's the actual message you get?

Comment: You have to create a bootable USB... but Debian may be a little tricky, because you maybe need two usbs instead of one. Let me check it. To create a bootable USB you can start [here](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/). There is also the command `dd if=<your iso image> of=<your device>`. Look for it, you can harm your computer if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: That's one of the installation step on network installer. `Detect and mount CD-ROM` and `Check the CD-ROM(s) integrity`.

Comment: It wants to detect CD-ROM because it is set like that in the boot priority in you BIOS. You have to access it, and change the boot priority.

Comment: @guillermochamorro no hope... Checkout the BIOS but it doesn't look relavant. Boot priorty No 1 is the HDD.

Comment: BIOS will boot in order. If you HD is not bootable, it will try to boot with next device and so on. Either way, you need a bootable USB first, then you can try modifying your BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a [USB attached DVD drive](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS804US804&ei=PAwRXZSlGOXJ0PEPlOusiAo&q=usb%203.0%20external%20dvd%20drive) (not a CD drive, as Debian nowadays takes as much as 4GB), or make a Live USB for installation, in which case you follow these steps:

1. Backup **everything** you care about on the drive in the PC you wish to install Debian onto.
2. Acquire a 4GB or larger USB Flash drive and erase its contents.
3. Create a Debian LiveUSB following these instructions https://wiki.debian.org/BootUsb or, if working from Windows, install [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) or some other LiveUSB creation app and create a LiveUSB using the [Live install hybrid ISO of Debian](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/) you wish to install. **amd64** is for Intel and AMD 64-bit processors, **i386** is for 32-bit machines. Both will contain many more packages than the shrunken net-install package.
4. In lieu of the DVD integrity check, verify the ISO downloaded with no errors and matches the checksum of the original ISO file, following these instructions: https://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/
5. With that LiveUSB in your destination PC, reboot your PC from the LiveUSB and enable UEFI Boot / disable Legacy Boot, and enable booting from USB.
6. Reboot, and install Debian, [following the prompts](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Debian#/Image:Install-Debian-Step-16.jpg). It will install itself to the drive you select in the PC, and allow you to retain the existing OS for a side-by-side dual-boot install, or you can remove any existing OS and use the entire drive, as you wish.

Comment: Your link points to the [Official CD/DVD images](https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/) (3 ISOs, you need a 4GB USB stick or larger and the first ISO). The [Live install images](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/) (1 ISO, fit on 2GB or 4GB USB stick) comes in different flavors (KDE, Gnome, XFCE, ...) and can be started without installation. Both versions can be installed from USB.

Comment: @Freddy, TY! Fixed link.

Comment: The debian install "iso" works by just cat-ing it to a usb stick (it's *both* an iso *and* a hard drive image). Why would someone spend money on a dvd-drive in 2019, unless she has a collection of unconverted cds/dvds? Also, most recent BIOSes are able to boot off the network nowadays -- you dont't even need a spare usb stick or sd-card.

Comment: The Customer, errr... Original Poster is always right. Therefore, I gave them a choice. Not a choice I would make, but, op cit. And, since they have not yet marked this as Best Answer with a checkmark at the left, they may still be waiting for something they like.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to install the Debian to the PC but it wants to detect
>   CD-ROM

So you DID start already with a debian USB Stick? (it = the debian? or it = the PC?)

With the correct ISO file? I checked and I saw a 250 MB netinstall and a 650MB xfce-CD install. But 650 MB cannot be a "full" installation, can it?. Where are the ~2G images?

I tried out a couple of installers lately, starting with Slackware...it did not work at all, for similar reasons (Mini-PC, no DVD). I had the slackware CD as ISO on a disc and the installer somehow pretended to support that (don't remember mounted or not), but then it crashed, and I started to look at these slackware bash scripts...good night!

Debian I think was the installer saying: don't be afraid, we are not touching your disk until you say so. Made me feel really safe.

I think today, it is easier (only way?) to do a **network install**. I had chosen slackware first because I was searching for an installation to *download*, as I was used from long time ago (starting with boot and root floppies).

Since you are asking for (any) "GNU/Linux distro": if you don't have a CD drive, don't start with a distro that doesn't work. But you should try that netinstall ISO on a USB, it won't be asking for a CD drive, I hope.

I finally installed archlinux over the net without installation problems.

(I also got that slackware 14.2 running (halfways), by extracting some of these .txz packages directly)

@K7:

> Reboot, and install Debian

Yes, but how? You also mean network? I have a nice opensuse live USB (takes an hour to boot, but works fine). But how can I install it to my SSD? For an installation you need also (access to) a bunch of packages. I feel *that* is the Q.

Added: under Linux, if you want to "use" a ISO-fs file, you `mount` it, you don't buy a CD Drive! If the installer can't do it, use another one.

Answer (score 0):

Slax is a distro debian based that can be easily installed.

The step for install this distro is:

1. Download the ISO file in https://www.slax.org/ (Download < 300 MB)

   - Choose into 32 or 64 bits version
2. Extract the .iso file into root of your partition

   - [Windows users] the root folder must be X:\ (where X is your partition letter)
   - [Linux users], extract the contains in /media/sdX (where X is your HDD)
3. Run the bootinst.

   - [Windows users]: Just run the X:\slax\boot\bootinst.bat as admin
   - [Linux users]: Open the terminal and run /media/sdX/slax/boot/bootinst.sh
4. Reboot.

Comment: But this was specifically about Debian, not about any Debian-based distribution.